# php variable height inside div

Tags: php, html, styles, height

I have the following php statement,

```
echo "<div style=\"background-image: url('$logo'); height: '$ratioxy';\"></div>";
```

I did this to make the height of the div variable depending on the background image.  The code correctly inserts the $logo variable, but not the $ratioxy variable.  The variable $ratioxy gives a value when I echo it, but it won't give the value inside the div.  Is there any reason for this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: drop the single quotes from arround $ratioxy

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
echo "<div style=\"background-image: url('{$logo}'); height: {$ratioxy}px;\"></div>";
```

[***Height***](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp) should be specified with *units* (`%`, `px`, `em`, etc) because "just some digits" are not obvious for browser. Also it should be specified without quotes.